# Specifying sameSite doesnt do anything google auth session cookies

Tags: node.js, authentication, cookies, google-oauth, samesite

My session cookies are getting blocked and the network tab is showing me this:
[image of the cookie in the network tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RNME.png)

Ive been stuck on this problem for three days and i dont know what to do

I tried putting this in the cookie session config but it doesnt seem to do anything

Index.js

```
const cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const listingRoutes = require('./routes/listingRoutes');
const userRoutes = require('./routes/userRoutes');
const authRoutes = require('./routes/authRoutes');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT;
const passport = require('passport')
const passportCfg = require('./passport')

app.use(cors({
  origin: [process.env.FRONTEND_URL, process.env.BACKEND_URL],
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,PATCH',
  credentials: true
}));


app.use(cookieSession({
  name: 'session',
  keys: ['weerit'],
  maxAge: 24*60*60*1000,
  sameSite: 'none',
  secure: true
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '100mb' }));

// Routes
app.use('/auth', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/users', userRoutes);
app.use('/api/listings', listingRoutes);



mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI)
  .then(() => {
    // Listen for requests
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Connected to db, listening on port ${PORT}`); 
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

this is the api endpoint that doesnt work when i fetch it but WORKS when i enter it in the url bar:

````
    //res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff');
    if(req.user){
        res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: "success",
            user: req.user,
            cookies: req.cookies
        })
    }else{
        res.status(403).json({ message: "Auth has Failed" })
    }
})```
````

Comment: i fixed it oh my good took me 3 days, this was the line of code that saved my mental health: app.set('trust proxy', 1)

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it oh my good took me 3 days, this was the line of code that saved my mental health: `app.set('trust proxy', 1)`, I put it before the cookieSession middleware